# Issue With Router.Parent.Navigate()

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm facing a Issue with `router.parent.navigate` In Angular 2.
And I don't know if this is Issue with Angular or something wrong with my code.

When I have parent Component `App.ts` which content config for routing and host all views.

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/angular2.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/router.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="./BusinessNameLookup/BusinessNameLookup.ts"/>
///<reference path="./LookupDetails/LookupDetails.ts"/>
///<reference path="./BusinessNames/BusinessNames.ts"/>
///<reference path="./BusinessWebAddress/BusinessWebAddress.ts"/>
///<reference path="./BusinessCategory/BusinessCategory.ts"/>
///<reference path="./ContactInformations/ContactInformations.ts"/>
///<reference path="./BusinessPurchaseAddress/BusinessPurchaseAddress.ts"/>
///<reference path="./BusinessImages/BusinessImages.ts"/>
///<reference path="./SurveyQuery/SurveyQuery.ts"/>
///<reference path="./ABN/ABN.ts"/>

import {bootstrap, Component, View, bind, Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {
ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
RouteConfig
, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, Route,
LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

/* Importing Application Components */
import { BusinessNameLookup } from './BusinessNameLookup/BusinessNameLookup.ts';
import { ABN } from './ABN/ABN.ts';
import { LookupDetails } from './LookupDetails/LookupDetails.ts';
import { Businessnames } from './BusinessNames/BusinessNames.ts';
import { BusinessWebAddress } from './BusinessWebAddress/BusinessWebAddress.ts';
import { BusinessCategory } from './BusinessCategory/BusinessCategory.ts';
import { ContactInformations } from './ContactInformations/ContactInformations.ts';
import { BusinessPurchaseAddress } from './BusinessPurchaseAddress/BusinessPurchaseAddress.ts';
import { BusinessImages } from './BusinessImages/BusinessImages.ts';
import { SurveyQuery } from './SurveyQuery/SurveyQuery.ts';
/* Importing Application Components */

import { BusinessModel } from './DataModels/BusinessModel.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})

@View({
        template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
        directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
        new Route({ path: '/', component: BusinessNameLookup }),
        new Route({ path: '/ABN', component: ABN, name: 'ABN' }),
        new Route({ path: '/LookupDetails', component: LookupDetails, name: 'LookupDetails' }),
        new Route({ path: '/BusinessNames', component: Businessnames, name: 'BusinessNames' }),
        new Route({ path: '/BusinessWebAddress', component: BusinessWebAddress, name: 'BusinessWebAddress' }),
        new Route({ path: '/BusinessCategory', component: BusinessCategory, name: 'BusinessCategory' }),
        new Route({ path: '/ContactInformations', component: ContactInformations, name: 'ContactInformations' }),
        new Route({ path: '/BusinessPurchaseAddress', component: BusinessPurchaseAddress, name: 'BusinessPurchaseAddress' }),
        new Route({ path: '/BusinessImages', component: BusinessImages, name: 'BusinessImages' }),
        new Route({ path: '/SurveyQuery', component: SurveyQuery, name: 'SurveyQuery' })
])

class AppComponent {
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_BINDINGS, bind(LocationStrategy).toClass(HashLocationStrategy)]);
```

As I write it this navigate me to Home page and view it in `<router-outlet>` attribute.
No I have been putting `this.router.parent.navigate(['/ABN']);`

This line I put it into function which called by button.
The issue start wile I press this button I have been navigated to the other page for while and back again to the home page and show question mark symbol in URL
`http://localhost:5000/?` and its also disappear also.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue when the `<button>` that handle the navigation event is located inside a `<form>` element

For example :

```
//Component function
gotoAnotherRoute() { 
  this._router.navigate(['/another-route']);
}
```

This template will refresh the page and add a question mark symbol in the URL

```
<form>
  <input [(ngModel)]="model.name"/>
  <button (click)="gotoAnotherRoute()">Validate</button>
</form>
```

This template will work properly and route as expected.

```
<form>
  <input [(ngModel)]="model.name"/>
</form>
<button (click)="gotoAnotherRoute()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Is this a real bug? Or does this behavior anyhow make sense. thx.

Comment: Not sure if it is a real bug because the standard behavior for an HTML form is to be submitted by the input with "submit" type, or the first button in the form if not submit type exist...

Answer (score 1):

just return false after navigating.

```
//Component function
gotoAnotherRoute() { 
   this._router.navigate(['/another-route']);
   return false;
}
```